# Why does it take more time to get information from a hard disk than from the main memory?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, speed

My current understanding of this question is fairly elementary. I read things like "main memory is closer to the processor" and "hard disk drives use spinning platters and magnetic heads which have to physically move". Further details are usually put into confusing or vague terms. Can somebody tie everything together clearly and eloquently?

Comment: That is the way it is designed and implemented.  Main memory is an integral part of a computer; it's essential to the operation of a computer. A hard drive is an external and optional peripheral.  Not every computer uses or requires a hard drive.  Therefore main memory is designed to have faster data transfers than external peripherals.  Money is spent and technology developed to maintain that hierarchy.

Comment: In theory a CPU could access data directly from a peripheral such as a HDD.  But that (programmed I/O or PIO) is impractical and inefficient, so all data transfers to/from peripherals (such as HDDs) use memory buffers.  So all data has to be transferred to main memory to be accessible.  Hence that's just one reason for the imperative to make main memory faster than any peripheral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets go get our data and see what happens:

Main memory:

Are we lucky and just used it very recently?  L1 cache hit, we get our answer back in 1 nanosecond.

Are we somewhat lucky and used it recently but not recently enough for the L1 cache?  L2 cache hit, 4 nanoseconds.

Ok, our luck was bad, we have to go out to the chips.  100 nanoseconds.

Hard disk:

First we have to search our tables in memory to figure out exactly where it is.  So long as it doesn't have to go to disk for this the time is going to be irrelevant in the final answer so I'll ignore it.

Ok, our data is in sector 123456.  Hard disk, please give me sector 123456.

123456?  Ok.  That's sector 456 on track 123.  Head, move to track 123.

Servo motor:  Click, click, click... 3,000,000 nanoseconds later, ok, I finally got there.

Now, lets figure this is a typical 7,200 rpm drive.  The platter is spinning 120 times a second so our average wait is 1/240th of a second.  We wait and wait and wait another 4,166,666 nanoseconds for the data to reach the head.

Note that this is also why reading big things from disk does much better than reading small things.  You want sector 123457 now?  Stepper motor:  I'm already there.  Read head:  Just coming up on the data now.

Comment: +1 for an answer that gets into why HDDs are so slow.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce it to its simplest:  Think of the CPU needing data.  RAM is a person that stands next to the CPU.  The CPU asks and the person immediately answers.  Very quick.

External peripherals like the hard drive go like this:  The CPU makes the same request, but since RAM doesn't have the data at the moment, it sends someone to walk to the hard drive.  The hard drive is like a children's carousel - it spins.  The data is written on sticky notes pasted to different parts of the carousel.  If you walk to it and the info you are looking for is there, great.  Read it and return.  If not, you have to wait for the carousel to spin around to get to the note you need.  Also, it isn't just on the edge, it may be more towards the center.  So you'd also need to search for it.  Once you get it, you return to the CPU.  Obviously just asking the RAM is faster than waiting for the hard drive.

Comment: +1 I like the analogy. The next level would be to explain how cache memory is faster than main RAM :-) Something like "CACHE is a next standing person closest to CPU". He/she looks into notes and if he has a card with data the CPU need, and handles it to CPU. But if the data is not in his/her purse, the CACHE needs to find the oldest used slot and handle it to RAM person first, and then take a new data from RAM before handling it to CPU. It takes more time. More, the RAM person is cheap and refuses to deal with a single data card, it says I will deal only with a bunch of cards, etc.etc...

Answer (score 0):

"Why does it take more time to get information from a hard disk than from the main memory?"

Because main memory (usually referred to as RAM) is MUCH faster.

There are 2 main types of storage in a computer, RAM and hard disk. Each has it's advantages and disadvantages and that is why a computer needs both.

Hard disk characteristics:
1. Relatively inexpensive.
2. It is permanent storage. Once written it will maintain the data indefinitely.
3. It is much slower than RAM.
4. Data going to or from the disk must first go through RAM. It cannot be directly accessed.

RAM characteristics:
1. Much more expensive than a hard disk. That is why a computer has much less of it.
2. Storage is volatile. That means when the computer is off it looses whatever data it contained.
3. It is much faster than a hard disk.
4. The contents of RAM can be directly accessed.

In recent years SSD drives have become popular. They are a form of hard drive that has no moving parts. They are faster than a conventional hard drive but still much slower than RAM. At present the main problem is that they are more expensive than a conventional hard disk, but that is changing. Eventually they will completely replace conventional drives.

One of the main jobs of the operating system is to make the most of these two very different storage media. Data that must be frequently accessed or changed (in some cases millions of times per second) is kept in RAM. Data that is not frequently used or must be stored permanently is kept on the hard disk. The operating system manages most of this without user intervention.

Comment: This seems to just restate the claim the question was asking about in slightly different terms, rather than explaining it.